# How to convert date time format in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, formatting

I'm using this query

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(MAX), GETDATE(), 22) AS Date
```

Result: 08/05/16 12:23:08 PM

But I want result like this 8/5/2016 12:23:08 PM

dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss a

Comment: You could use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505.aspx) -  `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')`. Just consider how it will scale, because it [can be costly on large datasets](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). Ideally formatting is a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: Actually I just want to compare my database date with API response date, btw thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of SQL Server 2012 the [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) function is available allowing you to specify the format of data types and is *locale-aware* so it will consider date formatting in relation to the session's language or optional `culture` parameter.

You can achieve your custom formatting like so: `FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')`

Note your requested format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss a` is incorrect as in the case of single digits you want to remove zero padding i.e. 10/8/2016 not 10/08/2016. That's why in the format string I use only `d` and `M`.

Also, pay attention to @GarethD comment about the cost on larger datasets.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathon , so easy :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the FORMAT function in T-SQL : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505(v=sql.120).aspx

Here is the code :

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```